# What are some ways to legally get around or postpone the J-1's 2-year home country residency requirement?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, visa

I am currently on a J-1 visa in the US. I have been a postdoc in the US since November 2019, therefore with the J-1's 5-year limit, I will have ~2 years left to be in the US unless I change to another visa or get a green card.

In about two months, I will do my second postdoc in a different US institution than where I am at the moment, which means I can only stay at my second postdoc for less than two years. For the kind of research I am doing, it is very likely that during the entire less-than-2-year course of my second postdoc, I will not have any papers published yet, or maybe just one. So, being able to stay at my next institution past my fifth year in the US is much more preferable for me.

I have heard about asking for the 2-year rule exemption, switching to O-1 or EB-2 NIW. I know that O-1 is based on achievements, but I am not very familiar with EB-2 NIW. If possible, I would like to avoid asking for an exemption by asking for permission from my country's consulate, because my skill is listed as being needed by my country. The other exemption route is government agency request, but I don't think public universities are government agencies (are national labs ones?).

I would be grateful if somebody could give a list of possible legal ways to avoid or postpone the J-1's 2-year home country residency rule, including O-1 and EB-2 NIW above. If possible with a brief explanation of what they are and special points to pay attention to. In case it will be helpful, I currently have 6 articles published in peer-reviewed journals, one article, and one chapter coming possibly in May 2023. My J-1 5-year limit will run out in November 2024.

Comment: Ask the new institution to help you with this.

Comment: +1 to Buffy's suggestion.  Each university has an international office whose staff are well versed in visa rules for academics, and can give personalized advice.

Comment: I'm a little confused, though.  What is the term of your upcoming second postdoc?  It sounds like it is less than two years.  So unless you are expecting that it could be extended, your visa status wouldn't really be an issue for that university, but for wherever you might find a job after that.

Comment: I disagree with Buffy, unless your international office is extremely experienced, they are unlikely to fully understand the possible legal maneuvers. You need a specialized immigration lawyer. Assuming you are not a medical doctor, you have identified the two reasonable ways out of the two year physical presence requirement. The first, is O. Unless you have multiple *Cell*, *Science* or *Nature* papers, I wouldn't expect this to work out. The second is the waiver. Some countries (like India) issue them all the time. Others, flatly refuse to issue them. If you are wealthy, there is EB-5.

Comment: You may also find this [handy chart](https://www.klaskolaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/J-1WaiverChart-1.pdf) helpful. (I have no business affiliation with this firm, although they represented me in the past.)

Comment: @NateEldredge, the contract of the job is for one year with a possible renewal of up to three years. But the problem is more about finding a more permanent position after my second postdoc. Unless you are lucky, you won't find any faculty opening that matches your expertise in a short period of time, or there are but you got rejected. The higher your publication number is the more likely you will land a faculty job. To be able to do this in less than two years sounds like a very lucky life to me.

Comment: @Ian, what about waiver through a government agency request? I may be able to get my second postdoc at a national lab, does national lab qualify to be a government agency?

Comment: @nougako I don't know how the government agency requests you mention work, but, e.g., US Department of Energy national laboratories are ran by federal contractors, and aren't agencies themselves.

Comment: It wasn't relevant in my situation, so I'm less familiar with the precedent, but I understand that say, an intramural lab at the NIH would count as an "interested government agency." However, the federal government has substantial bureaucracy and remember that you'd be dealing with both the HHS side and the State Department side. I think that would be a big ask for a potential PI with a big risk that you'd have to go "home" if it didn't work out.

Comment: In case it's useful. Here's what the NSF writes about acting as a 'interested government agency' https://www.nsf.gov/od/oise/visa-waivers.jsp